# Connecting a Lilypad to a WiFi network?

Tags: lilypad, arduino

I would like to connect my Lilypad Arduino to a WiFi 802.11 network that provides internet. What is the best way of achieving this? Can I use a XBee module and somehow interface with my home router? Is there a WiFi option available?

Thanks so much all!

Answer (score 6):

You can buy [WiFi modules with a serial interface](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9290), but they're a little pricy. Basically you control them via UART, and you send them AT commands similar to how you controlled dial-up modems in the olden days.

[image: WiFi module]

Comment: This is a great idea, and I even found a breakout board with this on it to make integration even easier. My only reservations were with power requirements and size. 

Thanks for your suggestion! I will definitely remember this for future projects :-)

Answer (score 4):

Expanding a bit more.

Davr suggested what I was going to suggest also. Roving Networks also makes a good set of BT modules.

To Expand. [ZigBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee) is a separate protocol completely from Wi-Fi. ZigBee is similar to BT in radiated power, which relates a large amount to range, but is different in that it is designed to allow multiple nodes to create a network, each node effectively expanding the network out by it's range. I hope this clears up that they are similar but not related.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Helped to clear up some questions I had :)

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to share my current solution with you all:

After chatting with Marcus and Madeleine at LittleBirdElectronics, we have come up with the following possible solution:

1) Xbee on The lilypad,

2) USB Arduino, Ethernet Sheild and Xbee combo to transfer messages to the WWW.

This is just one of many possible solutions, but for me this seems to provide the benefits of the low power and size requirements on the lilypad end by using the xbee instead of using 802.11 directly on the lilypad.

Besides, I already had a spare Arduino and Ethernet shield going unused, and wanted an excuse to play with xbee anyway! ;-)

Thanks all for your input! It was very useful in devising a solution.

Comment: I think solution suggested by me would be cheaper. But maybe Your is more solid, compact and easier to build. And You dad hardware already.

Comment: We considered both, but the module we found was expensive and overseas. Given I had an Arduino and an ethernet shield already, this became a little simpler :-) 

Thanks so much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use a XBee module and somehow interface with my home router?

Yes but You need to connect XBee module to Your router. You can try to find serial port on Your router board or by USB to serial adapter if Your router has USB port. Also your router should work under Linux (probably openWRT).

Answer (score 0):

How about a tiny wifi board like the ['The World’s Smallest ESP8285 WiFi Module?']: https://www.cnx-software.com/2018/04/30/the-worlds-smallest-esp8285-wifi-module/

BB-E01P module specifications:

WiSoC – Espressif ESP8285 WiFi SoC with 1MB internal flash
Connectivity

- 802.11 b/g/n WiFi with chip antenna
- Expansion – 8-pin (2.54mm pitch) with Tx/Rx, CP, RS, GPIO0, GPIO2, 3V, GND (Same layout as ESP-01)
- Misc – Jumper supports Deep Sleep Mode (AT+GSLP)
- Power Supply – 3-3.6V
- Dimensions – 10 x 14 mm
- The board is preloaded with firmware version AT v1.6 / SDK v2.2.

Comment: The fun thing about This question is that it was asked 2009 and ESP8266 was emerged at 2014 and it is practically the cheapest wifi module available. what a history